# How to use Adobe's React Web Component tool in AEM Maven project

Tags: reactjs, maven, adobe, aem, web-component

I'm unable to figure out how to use [@adobe/react-webcomponent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adobe/react-webcomponent) in an AEM Maven multi-module project.

I have tried a [similar tool](https://github.com/auniverseaway/react-dom-components) which has a [sample project](https://github.com/auniverseaway/pug-ranch-2018), and it works, but I would much rather use Adobe's instead.

Currently I can not find much documentation on this tool other than the [github page](https://github.com/adobe/react-webcomponent) and cannot find any sample project at all that demonstrates how it is used.

An ideal resolution would be a working sample [AEM Maven multi-module](https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype) project that shows how to properly use [@adobe/react-webcomponent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adobe/react-webcomponent) to have React components available in AEM site editor. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you got any reference for @adobe/react-webcomponent ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have *exactly* what you're looking for, but I did some work with that in [this branch](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-cif-components/tree/issue/CIF-857/ui.apps/src/main/javascript/aem-cif-search) of another Adobe project. It's about using a web-component to render a search box and a search results component written in React.